# Cómo introduzco datos en una tabla de una base de datos sql a través de un formulario html usando php?

Tags: php, sql

Estoy realizando una actividad en la que debo introducir los datos de una actividad en una bbdd a través de un formulario html.
Tengo la conexión encapsulada en otro archivo y sé que funciona porque la he usado para introducir usuarios a través de un formulario registro.
La función para crear actividades también la tengo encapsulada y no me da error aparente al introducir los datos a través del formulario, pero a diferencia del registro de usuarios, no hace nada tras enviar la info, no añade nada a la bbdd.

Conexión:

```
<?php


$conexion_mysql = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ifpdb");

if($conexion_mysql ->  connect_errno){
    printf("Error de conexión a la base de datos: %s\n", $conexion_mysql->connect_error);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Función crear actividad:

```
function crearActividad($actividad)
{
    global $conexion_mysql;

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO actividades (titulo, fecha, ciudad, tipo, coste, usuario) 
                 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $conexion_mysql->prepare($consulta);
    $stmt->bind_param(
        'ssssds',
        $actividad->titulo,
        $actividad->fecha,
        $actividad->ciudad,
        $actividad->tipo,
        $actividad->coste,
        $actividad->usuario,
    );
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->execute();


    if ($resultado) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

No estoy seguro de qué debe devolver la función o si debe devolver algo en absoluto.

Qué me falta?

Comment: El 'ssssds' de dentro de bind_param?

Comment: así me han enseñado a hacerlo y me ha funcionado para añadir usuarios via registro a la bbdd

Comment: Añade un else al if ($resultado) y comprueba el posible error SQL con $conexion_mysql->error.

Comment: Tienes 6 parámetros con ? y posteriormente tienes los 6 parámetros y el 'ssssds', imprime el error como indica Jose Carlos.

Comment: El 'ssssds' es el type, puede tranquilamente llevar si la longitud de la cadena coincide con la cantidad de parámetros https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Según la documentacion de Php como dice @Marcelo Zárate en su comentario lo estas haciendo bien, pero lo unico raro que veo es lo siguiente:
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
tu estas usando una variable que es la conexión en vez de llamar a mysqli directamente...

Comment: La función ```execute()``` solo la debes llamar una vez, esta linea la puedes eliminar ```$stmt->execute();```, luego te sobra una coma ```,``` en tu *bind_param()*, es decir, ```$actividad->usuario,);``` debería ser sin el coma ```$actividad->usuario);``` por eso no recibes nada.

Comment: Ok, no lo había utilizado nunca así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se trabaja con sentencias preparadas o cualquier otro método, lo suyo seria comprobar cada paso que haces y así te evites mucho dolor de cabeza, de esa forma te va a mostrar en pantalla el error que tienes y te será más fácil solucionarlo.

En tu código veo que tienes un coma `,` de más al final tu ultimo `$varible` de tu *bind_param*

```
$stmt->bind_param(
    'ssssds',
    $actividad->titulo,
    $actividad->fecha,
    $actividad->ciudad,
    $actividad->tipo,
    $actividad->coste,
    $actividad->usuario^^^,^^^ eliminalo
);
```

Tampaco es necesario hacer dos veces `execute();`

```
//$stmt->execute(); Elimina este
$resultado = $stmt->execute();
```

**Posible ejempo:**

```
/**
 * @param object 
 * - Supongamos que $actividad es un objecto
 * 
*/
function crearActividad(object $actividad) 
{
    global $conexion_mysql;
    // SQL
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO actividades (titulo, fecha, ciudad, tipo, coste, usuario) 
                 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    // Creamos sentencia preparada
    $stmt = $conexion_mysql->prepare($consulta);
    // Comprobamos que este bien la sentencia preparada
    if (!$stmt) {        
        exit('Sentencia prepare() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }       
    // Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parámetros
    $resultado = $stmt->bind_param(
        'ssssds',
        $actividad->titulo,
        $actividad->fecha,
        $actividad->ciudad,
        $actividad->tipo,
        $actividad->coste,
        $actividad->usuario
    );
    // Comprobamos que este bien los tipos y variables en nuestro bind.
    if (!$resultado) {      
        exit('bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    // Ejecutamos resultado
    $resultado = $stmt->execute();
    // Comprobamos que se haya ejecutado correctamente
    if (!$resultado) {
        exit('execute() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    } else {
        return true;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado. Estaba teniendo el error en el execute, le estaba pasando mal usuario y no podía ser NULL.  Gracias a la gestión de errores lo he visto!!

Comment: @Roman me alegro amig@ que hayas podía encontrar el error, al menos como he dicho, es importante gestionar los errores, te ahorrara tiempo XD

Answer (score 1):

Si te das cuenta la cadena de conexión la estas realizando correctamente.

```
<?php
  $conexion_mysql = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ifpdb");

  if($conexion_mysql ->  connect_errno){
      printf("Error de conexión a la base de datos: %s\n", $conexion_mysql->connect_error);
      exit();
    }
 ?>
```

Pero el fallo esta aqui segun la documentacion de php:

> $stmt = $conexion_mysql->prepare($consulta);

Podrias provas esto de esta manera:

```
function crearActividad($actividad)
{
global $conexion_mysql;

$consulta = "INSERT INTO actividades (titulo, fecha, ciudad, tipo, coste, usuario) 
             VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion_mysql, $consulta);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,
    'ssssds',
    $actividad->titulo,
    $actividad->fecha,
    $actividad->ciudad,
    $actividad->tipo,
    $actividad->coste,
    $actividad->usuario,
);
 /* ejecuta sentencias preparadas */
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

 printf("%d Fila insertada.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));

 /* cierra sentencia y conexión */
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Veras que los ultimos comandos cambian un poco me guiado segun la documentacion:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php